# AICC Course Web Page Content Package

Tags: package, scorm

I need a sample AICC package to test my LMS AICC API that refered from Open Source LMS called Ilias. Where can I find some AICC course package either it's free or needs to be paid?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

aicc.org has [sample courses](http://www.aicc.org/joomla/dev/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=51&Itemid=27) you can use to test an AICC implementation.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I already seen the example from aicc.org. However, I need to test further the ilias aicc API. Can you suggest other pre-made content? Thanks.

Comment: All aicc.org links now redirect to a goodbye message. Got any better places? Searching the web for aicc anything leads to a whole lot of nothing...